# DC/DC convertor max capacitive load

Tags: dc-dc-converter, decoupling-capacitor, load

In my aplication I need to use a galvanic isolator DC/DC convertor. One parameter in the datasheet (of DC/DC convertor) specifies that maximum capacitve load is 220uF and maximum mA output is 200

However in my application I need about 900uF.

Can I use a DC convertor ---capacitor 100uF--- and then LDO with current limiting (at 150ma) and use as much capacitance I want after the LDO  ?

Comment: That depends on the LDO. 900uF for a 200mA source seems quite a lot, but I guess it might happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolated DC/DC converters have relatively weak peak capabilities. Usually (in non-isolated DC/DC) overcurrent for a short time just heats the components a little, but in isolated the transformer can only deliver limited energy per switching cycle, so the power is limited.

The idea of limiting the current should work. Worked for me. I used a PNP, not even LDO.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the DC-DC converter. Can you use an other one? I think it is common that it can supply the peak current and that there is a thermal shutdown that can shut it down.

Why do you need 900µF ? When you need a buffer, the capacitor can be placed at the input of the DC/DC converter. When the converter can supply enough peak current, there is no need for a large capacitor at the output of the DC/DC converter.

When you need to charge a large capacitor, then some kind of current limiting can be used. A voltage regulator or LDO can do that. But when you need a lot of current the LDO heats up and reduces the current.

Is there something wrong with your application ? Perhaps a LC filter might help. Perhaps an other design/circuit will prevent this problem.